# How to use SkipWhile with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to filter objects with `SkipWhile` but it does not evaluate multiple conditions.

Below is a sample code demonstrating the issue,

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var result = numbers.SkipWhile(n => n < 2 && n != 2).ToList();
```

This query selects `2,3,4,5`, which omits the second condition (`n != 2`), when the first condition is `true`.

Is it possible to make the query evaluate both conditions?

**Edit:**

My actual condition is something like

```
... dateRanges
     .OrderBy(d=>d.Sequence)
     .SkipWhile(d => d.FromDate <= currentDate && d.ToDate >= currentDate)
     .Skip(1).First();
```

which is operating on DateTime filed, to select next object in the list

**Edit 2:**

I have created a sample program, which is something similar to my actual code

Class to hold data,

```
public class DateRange
    {
        public int Sequence { get; set; }
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var dateRanges = new List<DateRange>(){
                new DateRange{Sequence = 1 , FromDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1), ToDate = new DateTime(2014,1,31)},
                new DateRange{Sequence = 2 , FromDate = new DateTime(2014,2,1), ToDate = new DateTime(2014,2,28)},
                new DateRange{Sequence = 3 , FromDate = new DateTime(2014,3,1), ToDate = new DateTime(2014,3,31)},
                new DateRange{Sequence = 4 , FromDate = new DateTime(2014,4,1), ToDate = new DateTime(2014,4,30)},
                new DateRange{Sequence = 5 , FromDate = new DateTime(2014,5,1), ToDate = new DateTime(2014,5,31)},
            };

            var myDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 10); // A Date in Fabruary

            //This query selects {2, 2014/2/1, 2014/2/28}
            var selectedItem = dateRanges.OrderBy(d => d.Sequence)
                      .Where(d => d.FromDate <= myDate && d.ToDate >= myDate)
                      .First();

            //What I actually need to select is {3, 2014/3/1, 2014/3/31}
            //Which is next item of the list

            //This is what i have tried
            //But this query also selects {2, 2014/2/1, 2014/2/28}
            var nextItem = dateRanges.OrderBy(d => d.Sequence)
                  .SkipWhile(d => d.FromDate <= myDate && d.ToDate >= myDate)
                  .Skip(1).First();

            //Because, results of this part of query returns objects from {1, 2014/1/1, 2014/1/31} ...
            var unexpectdItems = dateRanges.OrderBy(d => d.Sequence)
                  .SkipWhile(d => d.FromDate <= myDate && d.ToDate >= myDate);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *is* evaluating both conditions - but as soon as the condition is `false`, the rest of the sequence is returned. As soon as `n==2`, `n < 2 && n != 2` is `false`. In fact, your condition makes no sense anyway - if `n` is less than 2 it *can't* be equal to 2.

Basically it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but the condition you're using isn't appropriate - and if you want to check your condition on *every* value rather than just "values until the condition isn't met" then you should use `Where` instead of `SkipWhile.`

EDIT: Now that you've posted a complete example, we can see what's wrong. Look at your condition:

```
SkipWhile(d => d.FromDate <= myDate && d.ToDate >= myDate)
```

Now look at the first item of your data:

```
new DateRange{Sequence = 1 , FromDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1),
                             ToDate = new DateTime(2014,1,31)},
```

And `myDate`:

```
var myDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 10);
```

Is your condition satisfied by the first item of your data? No, because `ToDate` (January 31st) is *not* greater than or equal to `myDate` (February 10th). So no items are skipped by `SkipWhile`. Perhaps you wanted `||` instead of `&&`? (It's still not clear what this query is meant to achieve.)

Comment: Please check update, My actual requirement is to select next object when the both conditions met...

Comment: @Nalaka526: Well without any information about your data and the result you're getting, we can't really help you. I suggest you edit your question to include a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem. I very much doubt that the problem is the implementation of `SkipWhile` though.

Comment: @Nalaka526: I've edited my answer to explain why you're getting the results you're getting. Basically I think you need to consider your condition more carefully.